# How do I construct an Html object from a String variable in Java controller code within the play (2.3) framework

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.3

I am *just* getting started working with the play framework, and I'm trying to understand the interaction between java application code, and the scala-based template framework (Note: I know absolutely nothing about Scala so far, beyond the fact that it's another language that compiles to bytecode on the JVM, and that your Scala and Java classes can interact).

I have a test1.scala.html template that looks like this:

```
@(title: String)(content: Html)

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>@title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        @content
    </body> </html>
```

As you can see from the top line, the template expects a String and an Html argument, but I can't figure out how to construct the Html argument from Java caller code!

I have tried a few variations in my controller class:

```
return ok(test1.render("My Title","It <em>finally</em> works!"));
```

This fails, obviously, because the second argument is a String and not Html, so I have an argument mismatch. (There's a runtime error:  `actual argument String cannot be converted to Html by method invocation conversion` -- which makes sense, but I was hoping for some magic here. :))

So I tried creating some Html from a String, figuring this was a likely helper class somewhere in the package and this might 'just work':

```
return ok(test1.render("My Title",new Html("It <em>finally</em> works!")));
```

This won't compile, because javac can't find an Html class. Ok, fair enough. Scanning the play documentation, there appears to be a play.api.templates.Html class (written in Scala) with a constructor that takes a String, so I try the full package-qualified name:

```
return ok(test1.render("My Title",new play.api.templates.Html("It <em>finally</em> works!")));
```

And this won't compile either: I get a Symbol not found for 'Html' in package play.api.templates.

So: what's the magic sauce that will let me turn my String (which contains a snippet of HTML) into an HTML object I can pass into the template?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Play templates have been factored out into the [Twirl](https://github.com/playframework/twirl) module, as stated in the [Play 2.3 Migration Guide](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Migration23).

`play.api.templates.Html` is now `play.twirl.api.Html`.

Comment: Excellent! That's the bit of information I was missing. Thanks!

Comment: import play.twirl.api.Html.  And it is now Html.apply(<string>).

<sarcasm>Or you could wait for the next minor version when it might be changed back again. </sarcasm>