# Generate fragments of html view template in Play Framework

Tags: java, templates, playframework

I would like to know how to generate some html in java, and then pass it to the view using parameter. How can I achieve something like this?

I've searched Official Play Framework documentation, but nothing found about it.

I know it is possible because we can pass one template to another using variable.

In my case I would like to generate that view on java.
F.e. I would like to create method display in inherited classes that will generate ready to use html code.

Please help

PlayFramework 2.2.6

Comment: So the Java code returns with a simple `String` with HTML code in it? If so then just use `play.api.templates.Html` to wrap it: `Html(javaGeneratedHtmlCode)`. After that just pass this `htmlCode: Html` to the template and render it `@htmlCode`.

Comment: Ok I founded this class and method. But when I use this constructor: `new Html("<P>aa</p>");` I am getting an error: `The constructor Html(String) is undefinded`. How Should I use constructor?

Comment: `Html` is a `case class` so you don't need `new`, this should work: `Html("<p>aa</p>")`

Comment: @AkosKrivachy he seems to be using Java (even though the question is tagged with `scala`)

Comment: @dcastro Ah, thanks, didn't see that. In that case I think you can explicitly invoke the `apply` method: `Html.apply("<p>aa</p>")`

Comment: And I may have mislead you, if you are using Play 2.3+ then it's already `play.twirl.api.Html` not `play.api.templates.Html`, this is discussed here and maybe this is a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24317346/how-do-i-construct-an-html-object-from-a-string-variable-in-java-controller-code

Comment: It's bad practice to generate HTML in Java. It should be done in the template. It makes everything a mess.

Comment: If so? Tell me how to create 4 independent views and inject them to view which is injected to main view in Playframework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer resolving my issue was given by [@AkosKrivachy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1697985/akos-krivachy) in a comment, which I marked as `Useful comment`.

Just for clarification, I am posting here working solution:

```
import play.api.templates.Html;
...
    public Html display() {
        return Html.apply("<p class="tested">aa</p>");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Why just won't use `play.twirl.api.Html`?

your action:

```
public Result yourAction() {
    Html myHtml = new Html("<h1>it works out of the box</h1>");
    return ok(yourView.render(myHtml));
}
```

**yourView.scala.html**

```
@(myHtml: Html)

My code: @myHtml
```

Works out of the box, at least for Play 2.3+

Comment: In play 2.2 which I am using it is in `play.api.templates.Html` package